# Creating a new column that shows percent change based on values of another column

Tags: python, pandas

This is my dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [10, 20, 50]})
```

And this is the output that I want:

```
    a      b      
0  10    100
1  20    20  
2  50    10
```

I have an initial value which is 1000. Then I want to create column `b`. The first row of `b` is 10 percent of 1000 which is 100. The second row is 20 percent of 100 that we got previously. And the last row is 50 percent of 20.

I have tried this code but it doesn't work:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
df.loc[0, 'b'] = 1000 * (df.a.iloc[0] / 100)
df['b'] = (df.a / 100) * df.b.shift(1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for [`cumprod`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumprod.html)?

```
(df['a'] / 100).cumprod() * 1000

0    100.0
1     20.0
2     10.0
Name: a, dtype: float64
```

Explanation: First divide by 100 since we're dealing with percentages. Then find cumulative product of the series. Finally multiply by 1000 which is your starting value.

---

```
df['b'] = (df['a'] / 100).cumprod() * 1000
df
    a      b
0  10  100.0
1  20   20.0
2  50   10.0
```